# Use iterator to control amount of Syphon Servers in Quartz Composer

Tags: quartz-composer, syphon

I'm using an iterator in Quartz Composer to render Images for multiple displays. How do I combine this with Syphon Servers?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the wrong approach. Using just one syphon server, you should render images for each display in a single extra large texture. I use the Billboard patch to control the placement of each display's intended image. Then there are software and hardware solutions for splitting an extra wide image across multiple displays.